# Union query return unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have combined two queries to get my required result, but it is not giving the result i want.

The queries are like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(rd.AMOUNT),0) as total from revenue_d AS rd JOIN  revenue_m AS rem on rd.RV_ID = rem.RV_ID Where MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 5   and YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE)= 2016

Union 

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(rd.AMOUNT),0) as total from revenue_d AS rd JOIN revenue_m AS rem on rd.RV_ID = rem.RV_ID Where MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 6 and YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE)= 2016;
```

The result it is giving me is like this

```
 +---------------+
 |     total     |
 +---------------+
 |       0       |
 +---------------+
```

While i want like this

```
 +---------------+
 |     total     |
 +---------------+
 |       0       |
 +---------------+
 |       0       |
 +---------------+
```

Even used Union ALL  but still getting the same result.

Comment: Use `union all` instead.

Comment: I did it with that also still getting same result

Comment: `UNION ALL` should do the job. [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/69283/0)

Comment: I think one of the queries return `null`.. you can try something like `coalesce(QUERY1, 0) UNION ALL coalesce(QUERY2,0)`

Comment: Perhaps You don't have any record in one of months . please check count of records in each month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `union all`.  `union` removes duplicates, so:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(rd.AMOUNT),0) as total
from revenue_d rd JOIN
     revenue_m rem
     on rd.RV_ID = rem.RV_ID
Where MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 5   and YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE)= 2016

Union all

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(rd.AMOUNT),0) as total
from revenue_d rd JOIN
     revenue_m rem
     on rd.RV_ID = rem.RV_ID
Where MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 6 and YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE)= 2016;
```

However, it is more natural to write this query using `group by`, although periods with no values will be missing:

```
SELECT YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE) as yyyy,
       MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) as mm,
       COALESCE(SUM(rd.AMOUNT), 0) as total
from revenue_d rd JOIN
     revenue_m rem
     on rd.RV_ID = rem.RV_ID
Where MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) IN (5, 6) and YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE)= 2016;
```

Or, using conditional aggregation (which puts the values in two columns:

```
SELECT YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE) as yyyy,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 5 then rd.AMOUNT else 0) as total_05,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 6 then rd.AMOUNT else 0) as total_06
from revenue_d rd JOIN
     revenue_m rem
     on rd.RV_ID = rem.RV_ID
Where MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) IN (5, 6) and YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 2016;
```

Comment: thank you. I was using phpmyadmin which has a bug in parsing 'all' keyword. so even with union all i got only one result. now i have install msql-workbench, and i got what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I think Always executing last query so you should write like this way,

```
(first Query) UNION ALL (second query);
```

Try this Query

```
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(rd.AMOUNT),0) AS total 
    FROM revenue_d AS rd 
    JOIN  revenue_m AS rem ON rd.RV_ID = rem.RV_ID 
    WHERE MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 5  AND YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE)= 2016)

  UNION ALL

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(rd.AMOUNT),0) AS total 
    FROM revenue_d AS rd 
    JOIN revenue_m AS rem ON rd.RV_ID = rem.RV_ID 
    WHERE MONTH(rd.SCROLL_DATE) = 6 AND YEAR(rd.SCROLL_DATE)= 2016);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?

UNION removes duplicate rows.

UNION ALL does not remove duplicate rows.